# Error in Maven when it tries to resolve dependencies, could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven

I want to include some libraries from ping federate in my maven, I have the jars and I imported in a lib folder. I have the information in .m2 but when I run my pom with Maven says me the next:

### This is my error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project identity.provider.attributevalidator: Could not resolve dependencies for project identity.provider.attributevalidator:identity.provider.attributevalidator:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: pingfederate:pf-commons:jar:9.1.1.0, pingfederate:pf-protocolengine:jar:9.1.1.0, com.unboundid.components:unboundid-ldapsdk:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find pingfederate:pf-commons:jar:9.1.1.0 in file://C:\Users\CesarMor\Documents\César\Kharon\identity.provider.plugins\Identity.Provider.Plugins\Identity.Provider.AttributeValidator/lib was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of pingfederate has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And here we can see pom.xml. I have written all dependencies. I don't know where is the error or where I am doing bad

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>identity.provider.attributevalidator</groupId>
       <artifactId>identity.provider.attributevalidator</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <name>[Kharon] LDAP Attribute Validator</name>      
       <properties>
             <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
             <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
             <javac.source>1.7</javac.source>
             <javac.target>1.7</javac.target>
             <jar.to.copy>target/${project.artifactId}</jar.to.copy>
             <cobertura.version>2.1.1</cobertura.version>
       </properties>
       <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>pingfederate</id>
        <name>pingfederate</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
       <dependencies>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.unboundid.components</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>pingfederate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pf-commons</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1.1.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>pingfederate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pf-protocolengine</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1.1.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.unboundid.components</groupId>
                    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
             </dependency>

       </dependencies>

       <build>             
             <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                           <plugin>
                                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                  <version>2.5.1</version>
                                  <configuration>
                                        <source>${javac.source}</source>
                                        <target>${javac.target}</target>
                                  </configuration>
                           </plugin>
                    </plugins>
             </pluginManagement>
       </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually check whether the version of identity jar is compatible with java version. If you are sure than you can try the project without using maven configuration. If all works well than try clearing maven .m2 folder as many a times, maven keeps the list of jars in cache and doesn't loads the newer jar.